# text substitution

Tags: bash

I have a list of files that are in the form `foo001.h21.tif` that I need to rename.  I know how to substitute strip off the end of the filename, but not the beginning.  I basically need to strip it so it can be saved as `001.h21.tif`.  Normally I would use:

```
for i in *.tif; do mv $i ${i%%.tif}; done
```

to capture everything preceding `.tif`.  Can someone help me with figuring out how to go the opposite way?

THanks!

Comment: You should tell which language you are using, as there is more than one regex flavour

Comment: @nicopico it's tagged bash and regex isn't needed

Comment: Yeah the tag was added while I was entering my comment...

Comment: @jordanm: It wasn't tagged "Bash" originally; I tagged it "Bash" based on the code sample. (It may actually be a different shell, but fortunately that shouldn't affect the answer too much.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` and `%%` are to suffixes what `#` and `##` are to prefixes. In your case, you can write:

```
for filename in foo*.tif; do mv "$filename" "${filename#foo}"; done
```

See [§3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  Can you recommend somewhere I can learn more about this?

Comment: @ShaunLangley: Yup; there's a link in my answer. :-)     (You may have seen the answer before I added the link.)